# Use basic auth conditionally in nginx

Tags: nginx, docker, environment-variables

I have an NGINX server built into Docker image which I want to use in both production and staging environments.

The problem is that staging environment requires a Basic Auth to be enabled in order to protect the server from prying eyes.

Is there a way to apply basic auth to nginx server dynamically? I can pass environment variable to nginx, or I can use pre-defined static hostname to distinguish production from deployment.

However, I'm not sure how to use this data conditionally in nginx.

Here's my config so far:

```conf
server {

    listen 80 default_server;

    # IF: %ENVIRONMENT% = 'staging' OR
    # IF: $host = 'example.com'
        auth_basic           "global";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    #

    root /var/www;

    location /health-check {
        auth_basic off;
        try_files /health-check.html =404;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

}
```

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Nginx doesn't support environment variables in server, location or http blocks, but you can replace the occurrence of a specific variable in your configuration file for the value of an environment value with [`envsubst`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/envsubst-Invocation.html) before nginx loads it.

With a configuration file such us:

```
server {

    listen 80 default_server;

    auth_basic ${BASIC_AUTH_ENABLED};
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;

    root /var/www;

    location /health-check {
        try_files /health-check.html =404;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

}
```

you can replace "${BASIC_AUTH_ENABLED}" with the value of the env var `BASIC_AUTH_ENABLED` by running

```
envsubst '${BASIC_AUTH_ENABLED}' < /etc/nginx/nginx.conf > /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

The first parameter `'${BASIC_AUTH_ENABLED}'` tells envsubst to only replace those occurrences that match that text (make sure to use simple quotes, otherwise parameter expansion might happen before executing envsubst itself).

If the value of `auth_basic` has the special value `off`, basic authentication is deactivated (see nginx [documentation on auth_basic](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_basic_module.html)).

As the entrypoint of your Docker container you can run a bash script such as:

```
if
    [ ${BASIC_AUTH_ENABLED} = "true" ] ;
then
    htpasswd -cb -B -C 10 /etc/nginx/.htpasswd ${BASIC_AUTH_USER} ${BASIC_AUTH_PASSWORD} ;
else
    export BASIC_AUTH_ENABLED=off ;
fi
envsubst '${BASIC_AUTH_ENABLED}' < /etc/nginx/nginx.conf > /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

So if you've enabled basic authentication, encrypt the password for the given user, otherwise, set the value of the env var to "off" specifically so nginx disables basic auth.

Comment: Hello, your example is not working if i set `export BASIC_AUTH_ENABLED="Value with spaces"`, it just puts the first word as `auth_basic` value. Any ideas?